# Is there a function when using Select by attributes, to select only the continents' annotations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, select-by-attribute, annotation

Annotations beginning with character "C" refers to continents and I want to select only these annotations.

Comment: Your question is currently not understandable. Maybe you could post an Image of your Attribute table to help us understand your issue.

Comment: I have modified the question. Hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't. Well, we can understand what you want, but without further details it is not answerable. What data do you have? How is it structured? With "continents' annotations", do you mean like *Asia* etc, or annotations within continents? Please expand your question to a few paragraphs to contain the proper information.

Comment: Annotations beginning with character "C" refers to continents and I want to select only these annotations.

Comment: Do you mean with  a `Like` statement?

Comment: Maybe. I just interpret my colleague's questions and I thought there would be a button or something what he is missed out. But if it's based on SQL querys, I think that will be the correct answer.

Comment: [Frame 2](http://xkcd.com/568/)

Answer (score 2):

Selection by attributes:

```
"field_name" LIKE 'C%'
```

Field_name is attribute that contains your annotations.

Comment: "field_name" like 'C%' works for some feature types, others use 'C*', so if % doesn't work try * before rage quitting. Remember also that some databases are case sensitive while others are not, so you might have to do "field_name" like 'C%' or "field_name" like 'c%' to get all your results beginning with c.